# Visiting PhD student in Australia - Temporary activity visa (408) clarifications

Tags: visa, student-visa, australia

I am an Italian citizen currently enrolled in a PhD program at an Italian university, and I am planning to travel to Australia for a research period lasting approximately 5 to 6 months, starting in February 2024. I have been exploring the temporary activity visa code 408, specifically for research activities, as it appears to be the most suitable option for my situation.

I have several questions related to the application process:

- Should I apply as a research student or as a researcher? I am currently a PhD student in Italy, so I believe the former might be more appropriate.
- What information should be included in the invitation letter from the hosting university for my visa application?
- In terms of financials, I receive a monthly scholarship. Could anyone clarify how much money I need to demonstrate as self-support ability? This information is not provided in the step-by-step guide.
- Additionally, should I translate my bank statement into English for the application process?

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: What advice did the hosting university offer you on these questions?